# Determining pose of an object in 3d space

Tags: geometry, transformation, 3d, rotations

Given a 3D model of an object centred at the origin, if I place a camera at position `(x,y,z)` and make it face the origin, from the image rendered the object appears to have changed its orientation (pose).

My question is, knowing the camera position how can I label the objects pose. i.e. how can I produce a rotation and translation matrix associated with the viewed pose?

For example, I am placing a virtual camera at each of the red nodes in the image below, for which I know their coordinates. My question is how do I define the camera or the object pose via a 4x4 transformation matrix?
[image]

Thanks